# Getting video off of Philips DVDR 3455H

Tags: data-recovery, dvd

I have this old DVR with a video on it recorded with my dad's camera. I can boot the player, but I don't have the remote, so there isn't any way for me to use the menus to transfer the video to a USB. I also can't find the remote online so I feel kind of stuck. I've thought of trying to get it straight off the hard drive, but I'm not sure if that's even possible. Any ideas for what to try next.

Comment: After looking through [the manual](https://www.download.p4c.philips.com/files/d/dvdr3455h_37/dvdr3455h_37_dfu_aen.pdf), I doubt this is possible. Are you still able to play the video? As a last resort, you may be able to find a device that can connect the component cables to a computer for the purposes of recording the output. That's off-topic here, though.

Comment: I can't test if the video is playable because I don't have the remote :(. I've looked inside and it has a ide harddrive.

Comment: You could try to pull the drive and use a hard drive dock (I've found the StarTech one's to be pretty reliable) to try to read files from it. There's no guarantee that the video will not be encrypted, though. Plus, there's no telling what the file system looks like or where the file is stored. Regardless, make sure to image the drive before doing anything with it.

Comment: [This forum post](https://www.avsforum.com/forum/106-dvd-recorders-standard-def/677258-philips-dvdr3455h-37-a-31.html#post22481810) indicates that there may be a workable remote.

Comment: Ah that's interesting. I'll try with a Harmony remote, thanks for the help :)